# C# - are there any events fired right after loading a form?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, load

I want to give the user the option to use a tutorial, the first time he uses the program. I tried adding it in the `Form.Load` event, but the forms shows up after the Messageboxes have popped up.

That's why I would like to know, are there any events fired right after loading a form?

If not, is there a way to perform actions right after loading?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should try the shown event, which fires after the form is shown for the first time.
Load happens before the form is shown.

Answer (score 9):

You could try using the `Shown` event but that might be a bit early too based on what you are doing but it does occur after the `Load`.

If you have any controls on the page you could trigger it off the controls `GotFocus` event.  Just make sure to put in checks to only do it once if using the `GotFocus` method.

MSDN [Form.Shown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx)

MSDN [Control.GotFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus.aspx)

MSDN [Reference to order of events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d%28VS.80%29.aspx)

> System.Windows.Forms.Control.HandleCreated
>
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.BindingContextChanged
>
> System.Windows.Forms.Form.Load
>
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.VisibleChanged
>
> System.Windows.Forms.Form.Activated
>
> System.Windows.Forms.Form.Shown

Answer (score 1):

The Shown event should do this for you.