# WinForm c#: Check first run and show message

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a winform application containing first run check. I've been following these 2 articles:

- [How can I check if a program is running for the first time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773748/how-can-i-check-if-a-program-is-running-for-the-first-time)
- [Windows Forms User Settings in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15013/Windows-Forms-User-Settings-in-C)

First run check is supposed to check if application has ever been run and if not, it should show some message to the user.
Problem i am having is, that this message is displayed **before** winform application is initialized/displayed and I am not able to find out why. 
Here is my code:

Program.cs

```
public static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Form1.cs

```
public Form1()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    CheckFirstRun();
}

private static void CheckFirstRun()
{
    if(Settings.Default.FirstRun)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(
            "First run");
        Settings.Default.FirstRun = false;
        Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

It shows Message box with msg: "First run" and after clicking OK button it shows WinForm. What I am trying to achieve is to Display WinForm first and if it is first run then show this msgBox.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you want to show this message in the `OnShown` event

Comment: What is "first run"? If you close the window and start program again - is it first run or first run is only after installation or after OS reboot?

Comment: There are many similar questions like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932012/c-sharp-are-there-any-events-fired-right-after-loading-a-form

Comment: @Zigma at `OnLoad` the form is not visible

Comment: @i486 as First run is meant first run of application ever (after installation)

Comment: Ok, but why the solution with `Form.Shown` is accepted as answer. It is not "first run of application ever" but first opening of form for current run. For "first run" you can use entry in Registry to set flag=1 after first run.

Comment: @i486 because if you will check my second link i am creating some user defined settings in such case (for each user of application there may be different settings). and using registry flag will lead to marking application as ran for all users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of calling  `CheckFirstRun()` from constructor you can call it [Form.Shown](http://Form.Shown)

[Form.Shown Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The Shown event is only raised the first time a form is displayed;
>   subsequently minimizing, maximizing, restoring, hiding, showing, or
>   invalidating and repainting will not raise this event

```
private void Form1_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    CheckFirstRun();
}
```

**Overriding OnShown**

The OnShown method also allows derived classes to handle the event without attaching a delegate. This is the preferred technique for handling the event in a derived class, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onshown(v=vs.110).aspx)

*Notes to Inheritors*
When overriding OnShown in a derived class, be sure to call the base class's OnShown method so that registered delegates receive the event, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onshown(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnShown(e);
    CheckFirstRun();
}
```

Comment: Overriding OnShown is preferred to registering an event handler

Comment: @Guillaume For what reason?

Comment: @GrawCube performance I guess. An event handler takes memory and is slower to invoke than a virtual method. You also have more control : you can call before or after events.

Answer (score 1):

Call `CheckFirstRun` from [`OnShown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onshown(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

> The Shown event occurs whenever the form is first shown.
>
> [...]
>
> The OnShown method also allows derived classes to handle the event without
>   attaching a delegate. This is the preferred technique for handling the
>   event in a derived class.

```
public Form1()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnShown(e);
    CheckFirstRun();
}

private static void CheckFirstRun()
{
    if(Settings.Default.FirstRun)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(
            "First run");
        Settings.Default.FirstRun = false;
        Settings.Default.Save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this event to fire the event after form has load.

```
private void Form1_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

MessageBox.Show("First run.");

}
```